# Best way store an array of items with details in SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to find out the best way store array of items with details in SQL table.
I have a user account database. The user have multiple input fields to enter multiple details like:

```
___ : ______ +(get more multiple field field)
```

User can input any details like

```
Output1 : Output2
Mobile : 2455...
email : sdf
city : dfs
Other : sf
```

On an average a user will use around 20 options

Since the fields (mobile, email etc.) are not known to me, I have to store `Output1` field with the answer field (`output2`).

I will be having a very huge user base, so I think it's not better to create separate tables for each user.

Is there any way to store and get the details in limited or single column.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model

Comment: maybe store the information as json... but that has some downsides like no way to sort with sql

Comment: How important is the data?

Comment: What is the problem with adding columns?

Comment: @MarkusKottländer - you're right, that's not a good idea. Better would be to have a details table with field `name` and `value` etc

Comment: @php_nub_qq - that is poor database design when you have many fields, especially when you don't know what they are

Comment: @scrowler it's even poorer if you create multiple tables for a 1 to 1 connection

Comment: @onetrickpony - you are right re: my answer - I think I was addressing something totally different from OP's question without considering the implications.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I completely agree

Comment: For the purpose i shifted to MongoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both the attribute name and value comes from users, a typical 3-table model of saving many-to-many relationship is a bit of overkill.

I would just kept users and their attributes in two separate tables:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| user_id | user_name | user_email   |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| 1001    | John      | john@doe.com |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| 1002    | Tim       | tim@doe.com  |
+---------+-----------+--------------+

+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| field_id | user_id   | field_name   | field_value  |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+  
| 1        | 1001      | Option1      | Option2      |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 2        | 1001      | Mobile       | 2345656565   |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 3        | 1001      | city         | dfs          |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 4        | 1002      | Other        | something    |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Possibly with some additional columns for sorting, tagging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 3 tables.

Table 1 - user.  PK is UserId.  Other fields are name, rank, serial number, etc

Table 2 - Attribute - Primary key is AttributeId.  Other Field is attribute name.  Examples of attribute names are emailAddress, cellphoneNumber, cityName.

Table3 - UserAttribute.  Primary Key is UserId and AttributeId.  Other field is Attribute value.